# Can future mortgage rates be predicted?

Tags: united-states, mortgage

Searching the internet, one can find a variety of predictions by experts about which way mortgage rates will go. (Up, currently.)

In the case of the stock market, conventional wisdom is that it's unwise to try too hard to predict the future, and in particular that individual investors shouldn't try to time the market.

Is the same true of mortgage rates, or are such predictions more reliable?

Comment: The internet is full of people who will tell you that they can predict any every aspect of the financial markets.  For a fee, they'll let you in on the secret.  If you get enough predictions, someone will always be right...

Answer (score 2):

Anything can be predicted, but the question of course is how precise and accurate the prediction can be. I can predict that the US mortgage rate will not reach >10% in the next 3 months for example. It's probably true, but you also can't do much with that information.

Mortgage rates are strongly influenced by market conditions and government regulations.

Market conditions are obviously unpredictable and you can have all sorts of black swan events that suddenly increase or decrease demand for mortgages. But people do model market conditions in various ways with some degree of success. So the market component is about as predictable as other market parameters.

Regulation can suddenly and dramatically alter the risk/reward profile of whole classes of mortgages, and it basically comes down who ends up being in charge of the government at that time and what they decide to do. I have never heard of any non-trivial political model that has any success so I'll go on a limb here and say it's a complete crapshoot.

The one thing that you can say is that they won't move very fast. Nobody really benefits from mortgage rates that change every day, so there are many mechanisms built into the financial system that result in a fair bit of inertia for mortgages. So whichever way they decide to move, it's a safe bet that they will move slowly over several years. But knowing which way they will move and where they will stop is very difficult due to the regulatory component I mention above.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can predict anything.  The problem is getting the predictions correct.  That's how psychics and similar scammers work: they make a bunch of different predictions in different places, and only talk about the handful that happened to be correct.

So I could make a bunch of predictions that interest rates will change by +/-1%, 2%, 3% in the next year.  A year later, I pick the one that comes closest to what actually happened, and loudly proclaim my success at predicting the market :-)

Answer (score -1):

> Searching the internet, one can find a variety of predictions by experts about which way mortgage rates will go. (Up, currently.)

That's true for a period from now to 15 years. After 15 years, interest rates are predicted to fall very gently (at least in the Euro area). Check the [ECB yield curve](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/financial_markets_and_interest_rates/euro_area_yield_curves/html/index.en.html) and select "Instantaneous forward rate" to get a prediction for the future interest rates.

> In the case of the stock market, conventional wisdom is that it's unwise to try too hard to predict the future, and in particular that individual investors shouldn't try to time the market.

I agree that stock market shouldn't usually be timed (except maybe if you somewhat want to reduce the risk of a large single investment at the cost of lower expected return, by time-based diversification), but however I can make a very reliable prediction of the stock market: if I retire after 35 years and withdraw my retirement savings over 18-year long period, the average duration of investment made today is 35+9 years or 44 years. I will predict that a stock investment will return more than a bond investment. For reference, AAA-rated Euro area government bonds yield 0.3% during 30 years (a 30-year long bond) so if we assume the remaining 14 years have the same yield too, then a bond investment increases by 1.003^44 = 1.1409x (which is probably less than the inflation during this period). A stock investment will probably yield 1.075^44 = 24.098x (this has a large uncertainty). In order to reduce stock yield below that of bond yield, the stock investment should immediately at the end of the investment period crash to 0.047x of its value before the crash (a crash earlier would allow reinvesting dividends at more favorable stock prices, which would be beneficial). Even the Great Depression didn't cause such a crash.

Heck, a stock investment increase of 24.098x at a dividend yield of 3% would pay back 0.72 times the value of the initial investment, every single year. You can guess two times whether I will sell stocks or live off the dividends if the stock market crashes...

> Is the same true of mortgage rates, or are such predictions more reliable?

If you care at all about the future mortgage rates, and if you are not planning to pay back your mortgage earlier than agreed, I recommend getting a fixed rate as long as the bank will give to you. Fixed interest rates are rather cheap now. Yes, it may be possible that variable rates will be very low as long as they have been in for example Japan, but it is a very cheap insurance to get a fixed rate.

Do note that if interest rates fall still more, it may be the case that the bank refuses an option to pay back part or whole of the fixed-rate loan early, or at least requires you to pay more than the amount of the loan (because the bank in such a case is unable to reinvest the money at the same rate). Variable rate loans usually can be paid back early partially or wholly without any extra costs.